# Django CMS installer fails when installing dependencies on OS X

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Just tried installing **Django CMS** on **OS X**. But I got problem while installing dependencies. Looks like there's a problem with MySQL-python.

Should Django CMS even be using **MySQL-python** on **Python 3**?

**This is the error I got:**

```
Please wait while I install dependencies
You are using pip version 6.0.2, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
    100% |################################| 167kB 145kB/s 
    100% |################################| 159kB 218kB/s 
    100% |################################| 237kB 472kB/s 
    100% |################################| 172kB 240kB/s 
    100% |################################| 196kB 302kB/s 
    100% |################################| 147kB 296kB/s 
    100% |################################| 159kB 279kB/s 
    100% |################################| 200kB 321kB/s 
    100% |################################| 159kB 315kB/s 
    100% |################################| 217kB 130kB/s 
    100% |################################| 4.6MB 196kB/s 
    100% |################################| 94kB 805kB/s 
    100% |################################| 110kB 753kB/s 
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/n9/t1wyb5y171df9032_fykvr8h0000gn/T/pip-build-akpiholr/MySQL-python
```

**Versions:**

Django stable
Django CMS stable

And Python 3.4.3.

Comment: Try installing mysqlclient first with `pip install mysqlclient` (it works with Python 3), then installing Django CMS again.

Comment: Version 0.8.5 use the newer driver, try to update to newer version